# How to calculate file hash with crypto++

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography, crypto++

I'm trying to convert this `qt` hash function to "c++ only" and using the [crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/) lib

```cpp
QString calculateGitHubFileHash(const QString& filePath) 
{
    QFile file(filePath);
    QString shaHash;
    if( file.open(QFile::ReadOnly ) )
    {
        QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
        QByteArray header = QString("blob %1").arg(file.size()).toUtf8(); // Need to be null terminated
        hash.addData(header.data(), header.size() + 1);
        hash.addData(file.readAll());

        shaHash = hash.result().toHex();
    }
    return shaHash;
}
```

A working reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    auto& mem = *static_cast<std::string*>(userp);
    mem.append(static_cast<char*>(contents), realsize);
    return realsize;
}

void curl(std::string& data, const std::string& url)
{
    CURL* curl_handle;
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.data());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.55.1");
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

std::string calculateGitHubFileHash(const std::string& filePath) 
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    std::string shaHash;
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // Get the size of the file
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        // Calculate the header
        std::string header = "blob " + std::to_string(size);

        // Read the file into a std::vector<byte>
        std::vector<byte> fileContent(size);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fileContent[0]), size);

        // Calculate the SHA1 hash
        CryptoPP::SHA1 sha1;
        CryptoPP::StringSource(
            header + reinterpret_cast<const char*>(fileContent.data()), 
            true, 
            new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha1, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(shaHash)))
        );
    }
    return shaHash;
}

int main()
{
    std::string json;
    curl(json, "https://api.github.com/repos/jajabu33/test/contents");

    // Using regex to parse the json to reduce code size, as this is just an reproducible example
    std::regex nameRegex("\"name\":\\s*\"(.*?)\"");
    std::regex shaRegex("\"sha\":\\s*\"(.*?)\"");
    std::smatch nameMatches, shaMatches;

    auto nIt = std::sregex_iterator(json.begin(), json.end(), nameRegex);
    auto sIt = std::sregex_iterator(json.begin(), json.end(), shaRegex);

    for (auto itName = nIt, itSha = sIt; itName != std::sregex_iterator() && itSha != std::sregex_iterator(); ++itName, ++itSha)
    {
        nameMatches = *itName;
        shaMatches = *itSha;
        std::string fileName = nameMatches[1];
        std::string sha = shaMatches[1];
        std::string localFileHash = calculateGitHubFileHash("C:/test.txt");
        if (sha != localFileHash)
            std::cout << "File " << fileName << " is not up to date\n";
    }
}
```

---

On GitHub json `test.txt` hash is `95d09f2b10159347eece71399a7e2e907ea3df4f` using the `qt` function on a local copy of `test.txt` it produce the same hash.

However, `calculateGithubFileHash` written with `crypto++` the hash is `07C467E5526EEDE9510953A974DB07F3138AFA57`

What is the correct way to calculate the hash appending the blob header to it?

Comment: Are these two identical files actually binary identical and same size? Have you done any debugging to see if `size` and `fileContent` are identical? Try `CryptoPP::FileSource` if you don't need the prefix `blob n` to be hashed.

Comment: Also if it's a binary file with a '\0` somewhere, it's possible that the hashing with stop early and not hash the entire file due to using string.

Comment: @TonyJ Yes, they are identical, the `blob` prefix need to be added or it will mismatch with the `file` hash returned on the Github json, what other way you suggest than "using string"

Comment: Are you testing `calculateGitHubFileHash(fileA)` and `calculateGitHubFileHash(fileB)` where `fileA` and `fileB` are identical? or are you testing `calculateGitHubFileHash(fileA)` against `QtVersion(fileA)`? The Qt version has a '\0` at end of header. The new version doesn't have it, because you are doing string concatenation.

Comment: You probably want to try `VectorSource` instead

Comment: You need to put `blob size` plus the content of of file into a `vector<byte>` https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_vector_source.html

Comment: @TonyJ I added a reproducible example, i also tried using a vector<byte> but it still mismatching

Comment: The original code adds a null terminator after the header, your code doesn't. `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(fileContent.data())` should be `std::string(fileContent.begin(), fileContent.end())`

Comment: @AlanBirtles replacing it to `std::string(fileContent.begin(), fileContent.end())` i continue getting the same mismatched values

Comment: You've added the null terminator and the hash didn't change? Seems unlikely

Comment: I just replaced the part you mentioned

Comment: `std::vector<byte> fileContent(size + header.size() + 1);` `memcpy( &fileContent[0], header.data(), header.size() + 1);`
        `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fileContent[header.size()+1]), size);`  `CryptoPP::VectorSource( fileContent...`

Comment: Also try do a byte by byte compare of qt version of `header` against c++ version. Also the data from `file.ReadAll()` and `fileContent`. They must all match in size and data. I wouldn't be surprised, if there are some extra bytes of '\0' or null, or '\r\n'

Comment: doing `header + ...` won't preserve the null terminator after it. You need to use `VectorSource` instead of `StringSource`

Comment: Is the hash in git created by Qt version in the first place?

Comment: @TonyJ i think i got it: https://pastebin.com/ck0vP8rt but its taking too much time to hash the files compared to the qt version